# Downloads stop when I close Putty. What is happening?

Tags: boot, services, deluge

I have Deluge P2P installed on my Raspery Pi. It seems the downloads stop when I close Putty, even though the Raspery Pi is still powered on. Should this happen? How can I prevent it? I don't have Deluge registered as a service because I prefer to control when it starts. To start deluge I run

```
/usr/bin/deluged -d &
/usr/bin/deluge-web &
```

Comment: when you close putty, you log out, and all running processes associated with that session, even those in the background, will be terminated ... if you make it a systemd service, you can make it "disabled", but still start/stop it using `systemctl`

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I do that?

Comment: oh, you don't know how to register it as a service?

Comment: I see, it uses the old /etc/init.d stuff ... I think you can still control it with systemctl though ... check `systemctl start deluged` for example

Comment: Prepend both line with a `nohup` e.g. `nohup /usr/bin/deluged -d >/dev/null &` . Or use screen as suggested in the answer. Or use tmux. If you start a process from the shell, the process is a child process of the shells process. If you close the shell (putty) its process is stopped and all child processes too. `nohup` forces the new processes to be children of the init process which runs as long as the machine is powered. So stopping the shell process has no affect. Screen and tmux are terminal emulators that keep the shells running even if you logout.

Comment: @JaromandaX to my understanding in Linux it's called "Daemon" and Windows it's called "Service". Is Raspberry Pi OS an exception?

Comment: @HoisZyrian - sure, why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `screen` program then use it in front of the deluge command when you start it `screen /usr/bin/deluged -d &`. You can also enter the start command in the `screen` after it starts. Then you will use the `CTRL` held down `a` then `d` to detach from the `screen` and leave `Deluge` running. You can at this point log out and back in and `Deluge` will still be running in the `screen` program, using `screen -r` will get you back at the `Deluge` running in it with a single instance running. To quit the running `screen` and any program in it `CTRL` held down then `q` twice. You can do the same with the web interface and when starting the `screen` you can using an option to name them to make it easier to get back to kill them off if needed/wanted, with a `screen -r name` to resume it rather find the process number to get back.